# Include contents of a branch of a repo into my project folder and update both

Tags: git

We have a library that has common code. Then, there are multiple project folders. For a project to reuse and add more code to library, the project first creates a branch of the library.

Now, we need to get the contents of that branch into the project folder and update it.

The project folders are remote repos that developers will branch and keep adding code to it. But, the developers also want to get the contents of the branch of the library into their project branches and keep adding to the common code of the library branch.

Once they are done, they want to be in a state where the branch of the FL and the copy of that branch in their project folder branches are up-to-date.

How to do this?